# My .htaccess File Is Empty. How Can I Fix This?

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

I was looking for a way to prevent file extensions from showing in the browser's address bar. I found some solutions in here that i had to change .htaccess in my www root folder. but when I open the file for opening it, it's empty. how can I fix this. is there any other solutions to prevent the file extensons from showing in the address bar? I don't want to use  tag.
thanks for your help

Comment: What kind of extensions are you trying to "hide"?

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the following in your htaccess file..

This will remove ext from local.

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L,QSA]

This will remove ext from wide.

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^.]+.)+php\ HTTP

RewriteRule ^(.+).php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

Its a long shot but worth  a go. cheers.